# Logger is not a function error in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging

As in my previous questions I said, I am trying to create an HTTP server, testing some middlewares codes, but in my code right now is giving basically the same error from another times, but I can't see where I am getting this wrong.

My code :

**logger.js**

```
var http = require('http');
var connect = require('connect');
var app = connect();
// setup logger middleware
app.use(connect.logger());
// actually respond
app.use(function(req, res) {
res.end('Hello World!');
});
http.createServer(app).listen(8080);
```

He points out to the `connect.logger()` even if I am using `app.use()`, still gives me this error.

> connect.logger is not a function

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24692435/nodejs-connect-error-has-no-method-logger

Comment: I didn't saw that question, if you want, I cant delete my question, but I don't want being pointed as duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NodeJS Connect error - has no method 'logger'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24692435/nodejs-connect-error-has-no-method-logger)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect no longer comes with a built-in logger! Try using some logging library like [morgan](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan)

```
var http = require('http');
var connect = require('connect');
var logger = require('morgan');

var app = connect();
// setup logger middleware
app.use(logger("combined")); //Without one string in logger() it will give deprecated morgan format, so it needs to use some string for work, the documentation it say so.

// actually respond
app.use(function(req, res) {
   res.end('Hello World!');
});
http.createServer(app).listen(8080)
```

Comment: I just edited your answer in app.use(logger()); to app.use(logger("combined")); because it says in the documentation that it needs a string for return, without it, it gives the error "deprecated morgan format".